# UIWebView can not play local video file with big size

Tags: ios, iphone, video, uiwebview

I'm building an app with in-app browser which will load a local `html` file to view text, audio and a video. I save all these media files in Documents directory. The problem is when I run the app on device and the `UIWebView` load the video file (mp4 format, >500mb - is the file size is too big for iOS?) I always get the warning from console:

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=569212928) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

But when I run it on simulator, it works just fine.

And when I replace it with another video file which is just about 100MB, it worked on both simulator and device. The device I'm using is iPhone 4s, iOS 6.

Am I missing something? I know that the error code 12 is about memory warning, so do I have to do something about memory management?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/39736-a-crash-when-exiting-an-overlay-scene-with-a-webview-only-happens-in-ios-device-testing/

Comment: Hi @Radu
I think the problem is not the UIWebView. Because when I run it on device, it won't crash, and the frame for the video is show with a slash through the Play button, and I can not play the video while the console gave me the warning as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'm pretty sure I know why this is happening.  I believe it has to do with the fact that apple's physical devices use a hardware H264 decoder.  When you are trying to play the video using the `<video>` tag, it is attempting to load the entire thing into the decoder's buffer, which isn't big enough.

I think that if you tried streaming it (instead of the local progressive download) it would work.  But that's a lot more complicated. I don't think it has anything to do with the software, I'm pretty sure it's due to the limitations of the hardware.